# mongoose custom getter not working as expected

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to implement a custom getter with mongoose but it isn't working properly or as expected.

This is my model:

```
const itemsShapePrefix = 'item-';
const itemsModel = new Schema({
  shape: {
    type: String,
    default: 'rect',
    required: true,
    enum: [
      'rect',
      'circle',
      'capsule',
      'rhombus',
    ],
    get: v => `${itemsShapePrefix}${v}`
  }
});
```

But when doing the `model.find()`, I get a list like this:

```
[{"shape": "circle"}]
```

And I actually would like to get it like this:

```
[{"shape": "item-circle"}]
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or what I should change to get this behavior?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not process it after `.find`? Or save it after formatting `pre('save, () => {})`?

Comment: @molamk I just wanted to know if it's possible to do it with the default mongoose methods